# Use cookie for Javascript function

Tags: javascript, cookies, jquery-cookie

I have a Javascript function :

```
$('.myclass').click(function() {
  $('.myclass2').each(function(e) {
    $(this).removeClass('myclass3').addClass('myclass4');
  });
});
```

I would wish that the changes remain all the time for the user with [jquery cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).

Do you know how can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [jQuery Cookie](https://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/) plugin:

Set a cookie

```
$.cookie("example", "foo");
```

Get a cookie

```
alert($.cookie("example"));
```